# End in sight for new Site Design?

Tags: discussion, site-design

My last post about Site Design occurred a [little over a year ago](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1971/4152). Just because I was curious, I went out on Meta and found a new post [concerning site design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/326798/249769). While we haven't had movement yet, two other of the ten sites out there have at least started their site design transition. Those are:

- [Code Golf & Coding Challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions) ([CG Meta Post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17725))
- [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions) ([Anime Meta Post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4245/44999))

The design on [Code Golf is live](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17760), though I'm not sure about Anime. I don't see a "live" Meta post for it.

If  you look on the Meta post, you'll see we are about 1/2 way down the list. Last update on there was June 12 by Catija, though she did comment on June 13 stating Anime's site design is being completely redone.

There does seem to be some sort of end in site. We've all been waiting for the design to come and it looks as though we are seeing some action. It does say in Catija's post the site order for site design was decided by oldest site graduation to newest. Keep your eyes on the Meta post which might give us further information. I'd assume it's still going to be several months down the road before we see any action ... in fact, I wouldn't hope to see anything until 2020 (just my SWAG). Stay tuned.

Comment: FYI, the design on [Anime & Manga is also live now](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4272).

Comment: @AndrewT. - I kinda like their design elements ... looks pretty kewl! Hopefully ours will as good or better :o)

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our other CMs from last week: [Custom MVM&R design and logo - Information gathering](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2113/67918) :)

Comment: @V2Blast - Well ahead of you ... Catija has been diligent! :o)